# Intercepting network traffic for a particular application

Tags: windows-networking

I am working on Windows. Lets say I am running a Twitter app. I want to intercept all the network packets that this app is sending or receiving at runtime. I wish to look for certain packet (segment) features like TCP destination port, windows size etc. and based on this information I wish to perform certain actions. Basically I want all the information that is available to a traffic analyzer like Wireshark or MS Network Monitor. How can I accomplish this on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand completely what you're aiming at - from what I understand, you could start Wireshark, log the relevant info, and then perform "certain actions" based on the data you could retrieve from this log - even automatically with some scripting.

Comment: I want to do this at runtime (while the application is running). I want to intercept the packets that the app is sending or receiving and take certain actions.

Comment: Please have you a solution to this problem ?because i have the same probleme